# What does a ">" after a pseudo-class (:first-child) do in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I encountered the following selector in a menu template:

`#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a`

I'm not asking what the greater than character or *:first-child* pseudo-class do, but how these two work together to select what they select.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *"What does a “>” after a pseudo-class (:first-child) do in CSS?"* It does the same thing as it always does: selecting children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#cssmenu ul ul
```

Selects the unordered lists inside of the unordered lists inside the element with id "cssmenu".

```
li:first-child
```

Selects the first list item in each of the unordered lists selected above.

```
> a
```

Selects the direct, and only direct, descendant anchors of each of the list items selected above.

Comment: What confuses me is that the selector applies not only to ul ul li:first-child > a, but also to ul ul ul li:first-child > a

Comment: Right, because `ul ul ul` meets all of the criteria above (unordered lists inside of unordered lists inside the element with id "cssmenu"). If you *don't* want to select those, you could try `#cssmenu > ul > ul > li:first-child > a` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's just your garden-variety **[child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**.  In this case it selects the child of the first list item.

Answer (score 0):

The `:first-child` selector allows you to target the first element immediately inside another element and the `>` selector just does what it does the best, i.e. selects the direct anchors inside it.